# How do I separate the Mobile app user and web app user in REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-7

There are different user like Coach, Athlete, Meet Director and Admin. Coach & Athlete are mobile app users, Admin are Web app user, Meet Director are both mobile & web app user.
Please suggest any gem or share your thoughts.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, and I will make sume assumptions in order to make a suggestion:

- you have the same service (same api entry point) served to all different Roles ("role" being the key word)
- Depending on the role, the user will have different scope of action withing that same service

Based on this, I would suggest you to assign your service with checkpoints based on the role.

The approach I suggest below is quite naive, but works as if your entry point as a 'factory', producing the response based on the users's role...

I would say one thing that might prove valuable in the future is to allow an user to have multiple roles. That would grant the user both coach and athlete access, for exemple, if that makes sense.

Ex:

```rb
class Api::V1::SomethingController < ApplicationController

  ...
  def my_service
     user = User.find(params[:id])
     
     # Makes sure we have an user
     render json: {}, status: :bad_request unless user

     # performs differently based on the role
     my_service_for_coaches if user.roles.include? 'coach'
     my_service_for_athletes if user.roles.include? 'athlete'
     ....
  end

  def my_service_for_coaches
    ...
  end
  ...

end
```

but let me add a suggestion of approach to take